# Javascript byte array to Int32Array equivalent in Java

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, integer, unsigned-integer

I have a javascript snippet which will take 4 byte and convert that in to int value.

```
var bufView = new Uint8Array([0xe4, 0x0e, 0x00, 0x00]);
var a = new Int32Array(bufView.buffer.slice(0,4))[0]
console.log(a);
```

Output of the above code is **3812**

I want to do the same operation in Java as well where I have

```
byte[] bytes = {(byte) 0xe4, 0x0e, 0x00, 0x00};
```

I have searched whole internet but I could not see any results related to this. How can we achieve this?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html

Comment: @IłyaBursov could you please elaborate how to achieve this using ByteBuffer.
`ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);`
`bb.put((byte) 0xe4);`
`bb.put((byte) 0x0e);`
`bb.put((byte) 0x00);`
`bb.put((byte) 0x00);`
`bb.rewind();`
`int val = bb.getInt();`

This code returns a different value.

Comment: something like `ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();`

Comment: `ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getInt();` returns -468844544

Comment: ah, you need LE then `ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt()`

Comment: Cool. Its working. I am able to get the same output.

Answer (score 1):

As Ilya Bursov commented, I could able to achieve the same using the following Java code snippet.

```
byte[] bytes = {(byte) 0xe4, 0x0e, 0x00, 0x00};
int anInt = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getInt();
System.out.println(anInt);
```